# Using webdriver.io in visual studio

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2017, webdriver-io

How would a start to create webdriver.io tests in visual studio. Then how would I run them? It seems as though I need to create a node project in visual studio. But then how would I run them?

Comment: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can handle this. I would go with #1 or #2. With #2 once you are all setup you can just right click the test suite and run them.

1. Run them from the command line
2. Install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner) extension, add some npm scripts, and run them from the Task Runner Explorer
3. Create some gulp tasks and run them from the Task Runner Explorer